# List of English words

Tags: data-request, language

I'm writing a program that requires a list of English words, such as that used by a spell checker. I have been unable to find any such word lists whatsoever, even after trying 2 search engines.

Answer (score 12):

You can download an [Aspell Dictionary](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/0index.html), then  [convert it to simple list of words](https://superuser.com/q/137957/116475):

```
aspell -d en dump master | aspell -l en expand > my.dict
```

A few other [dictionaries](http://wordlist.aspell.net/other-dicts/).

Answer (score 9):

Use [wordnet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/), it's an academic project but a de facto for various purposes including the one you asked for. There are also higher semantics modeled that you can use for various functions.

It's also convenient to query and integrate it into your app.

Answer (score 7):

If you're on a Mac, there's a list of words, 1 per line, in the file `/usr/share/dict/words`. The `usr` folder is hidden by default, but you can view it by following the following steps:

1. Open the Finder.
2. In the menu, go to Go->Go to Folder or press Cmd-Shift-G.
3. In the box, type `/usr/share/dict`.
4. You'll see a list of files. Copy the file called `words` to whatever location you need it in.

Comment: I tried that, but there are many words not in it.

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to use Google, the general terms to use would be :

From the linguisitics community:

- 'text corpora' or 'text corpus'  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_text_corpora) or

For the password cracking community :

- 'wordlist' (one word, might need to keep quoted; http://www.openwall.com/wordlists/)

Comment: Password crackers are also utilizing Twitter and Facebook now to incorporate the latest slang and idioms.

Answer (score 4):

Ask around on the [Omega Wiki](http://www.omegawiki.org/Meta%3aMain_Page), formerly known as the Ultimate Wiktionary or WiktionaryZ. They have all the data from all the various wiktionaries in a relational database. This means that they also have inflected and conjugated forms, comparatives/superlatives and whatnot. And not just for English. Basically they can produce pretty much any list you like, and indeed (if you wish) not just a list but structured data.

Answer (score 2):

Thought I would share that you can also find different kinds of word lists [here](http://www.wordgamedictionary.com/word-lists/) and many of them are downloadable for free in `json` format.

Answer (score 2):

### Google N-grams

As I mentioned [elsewhere](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5435/where-can-i-get-a-complete-word-and-phrase-list-for-english/7547#7547), Google Ngrams are perhaps the largest corpus of English words:

- http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html

Keep in mind that it contains improper English words as well, but it's easy to exclude them by setting use frequency threshold.